# UIButton Image + Text IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uibutton

I need a `UIButton` with **image & text**. Image should be in the top & text comes under the image both should be clickable.

Comment: Hope this helps,
See [UiButton with both TEXT and IMAGE][1]
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926581/uibutton-with-picture-and-text


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926581/uibutton-with-picture-and-text

You can then add a UITapGestureRecognizer on your view to handle custombutton clicks.

Comment: See the accepted answer and this http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/03/12/uibutton-edge-insets/ about UIButton Edges

Answer (score 334, accepted):

I see very complicated answers, all of them using code. However, **if you are using Interface Builder**, there is a very easy way to do this:

1. Select the button and set a title and an image. Note that if you set the background instead of the image then the image will be resized if it is smaller than the button.[image: IB basic image and title]
2. Set the position of both items by changing the edge and insets. You could even control the alignment of both in the Control section.

[image: IB position set]
[image: IB Control set]

You could even use the same approach by code, without creating UILabels and UIImages inside as other solutions proposed. Always Keep It Simple!

EDIT: Attached a small example having the 3 things set (title, image and background) with correct insets
[image: Button preview]

Comment: This is correct. You'll want to use the edge insets on the title and image to align the two correctly. You can do this in code by setting the titleEdgeInsets and contentEdgeInsets properties.

Comment: yes, it is almost correct. just you have to set the `Background` image instead of the `Image`, otherwise you won't see the title not even set the inset values to reposition the title.

Comment: Not correct? Actually, you can see the title, the image and the background, all together. I am using this technique for my buttons and it works correctly.

Comment: @AngelGarcíaOlloqui, positive, it is not working. a minute ago I've tried your version in `Xcode 4.4` on a real device, the `Title` did not shown when you set the `Image` and the `Title` together and the `Title` does not show in the _Interface Builder_ either, in my experience they have never worked together because the `Image` always override the `Iitle`.

Comment: It does work but you have to change the content insets for both (title and image), setting values that do not overlap with each other. We are using this trick in many different buttons, all of them with a background (a gray button shape for example), an image on the left (a share icon for example) and a text (the share text for example). Check it again, it is a a great way to create such buttons!

Comment: I edited my answer with a small screenshot of a button with the 3 properties set and working. I hope it helps :)

Comment: I had trouble with this too.  If your title is not showing up, try setting a negative left offset for it.  It looks like IB automatically pushes it out to the right of the image.

Comment: Can you give an example of what insets value we have to set for both Image and Title to appear? I can't get the Title to appear..

Comment: For Content, set Inset left & right 0.
For Image, set Inset left 0 and right e.g. 50.
For Title, set Inset left -51 and right 0.

Comment: I found that once I set an image it wiped out the text attributes. I reset those (font, colour, etc) and then everything was fine!

Comment: I had to change my control alignment to the two far right options (vertical two-sided arrow, and horizontal two-sided arrow) to get this to work.

Comment: Guys, my issue was resolved when I set negative left offset as @brians suggested. I think brians is right that text is being pushed towards right.

Comment: This does only display the image and the text side by side, right? Is there a way to change the orientation from top to bottom? This is what the original question states and what I'm looking for as well. Thanks!

Comment: For those using Xcode 8, you may not see the Edge property. The text may disappear after adding an image as well. It changes the text to white and if you are on a white background, it looks like it disappeared. Change the text color and it'll appear close to the image. You can the adjust the insets under Size inspector.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. it helped me understand better the interface builder. Now is there a way to resize the image in the button? like, how could I force the image to be 32x32 on a 375x80 button?

Comment: I had the problem of "invisible label", and solved it in reducing image size (in Preview.app). I was using a 500*500 icon for a 100*30 button…

Comment: @AnthoPak what is preview.app and how to open it?

Comment: @YashJain This is the stock Preview application on MacOS. But you can use any image resizing tool to achieve this.

Answer (score 71):

I think **you are looking for this solution** for your problem:

```
UIButton *_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 128.f, 128.f)]; // SET the values for your wishes
[_button setCenter:CGPointMake(128.f, 128.f)]; // SET the values for your wishes
[_button setClipsToBounds:false];
[_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"jquery-mobile-icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // SET the image name for your wishes
[_button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.f]];
[_button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // SET the colour for your wishes
[_button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; // SET the colour for your wishes
[_button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, -110.f, 0.f)]; // SET the values for your wishes
[_button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouchedUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; // you can ADD the action to the button as well like
```

...the rest of the customisation of the button is your duty now, and don't forget to add the button to your view.

**UPDATE #1** and **UPDATE #2**

or, **if you don't need a dynamic button** you could add your button to your view in the *Interface Builder* and you could set the same values at there as well. it is pretty same, but here is this version as well in one simple picture.

you **can also see the final result** in the *Interface Builder* as it is on the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: EdgeInsets only works when you have "set button image" and when you set button image you cant see title. And if you set background image then EdgeInsets can not apply to image . and you can see title. So, you can't set edgeinsect to both at same time.

Comment: @BadalShah, yes, there are some scenarios (depending on button's size, image size, title's length, etc...) when what you said is true and you can't see the _title_ and the _image_ at the same time because the _image_ pushes out the _title_ of the visible area; but that scenario is not a generic at all, the generic situation is that both _title_ and _image_ could and will appear at the same time.

Answer (score 41):

**Xcode-9** and **Xcode-10** Apple done few changes regarding Edge Inset now, you can change it under size-inspector.

Please follow below steps:

**Step-1:**
Input text and select image which you want to show:

[image]

**Step-2:**
Select button control as per your requirement as shown in below image:

[image]

**Step-3:**
Now go-to size inspector and add value as per your requirement:

[image]

Answer (score 21):

swift version:

```
var button = UIButton()

newGameButton.setTitle("Новая игра", for: .normal)
newGameButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "energi"), for: .normal)
newGameButton.backgroundColor = .blue
newGameButton.imageEdgeInsets.left = -50
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

In my case, I wanted to add `UIImage` to the right and `UILabel` to the left. Maybe I can achieve that by writing code (like the above mentioned), but I prefer not to write code and get it done by using the `storyboard` as much as possible. So this is how did it:

**First,** write down something in your label box and select an image that you want to show:

[image]

And that will create a button looking like this:

[image]

**Next,** look for `Semantic` and select **Force Right-to-Left** (If you don't specify anything, then it will show the image to the left and label to the right like the above image):

[image]

**Finally,** you'll see `UIImage` to the right and `UILabel` to the left:

[image]

To add space between a label and an image, go to the **Size inspector** and change those values depending on your requirement:

[image]

**That's it!**

Comment: Made my day!!  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your image name here"];
button.titleLabel.text = @"your text here";
```

but following code will show label above and image in background

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your image name here"];
button.titleLabel.text = @"your text here";
```

There is no need to use label and button in same control because UIButton has UILabel and UIimageview properties.

Comment: I need to position the image in the top & the text below the image both should be clickable..

Answer (score 5):

Use this code:

```
UIButton *sampleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[sampleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 200, 52)];
[sampleButton setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sampleButton setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
[sampleButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"redButton.png"] 
stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sampleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:sampleButton]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this code:

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 44.0f);///You can replace it with your own dimensions.
    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 35.0f, 50.0f, 44.0f)];///You can replace it with your own dimensions.
    [button addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 4):

Make `UIImageView` and `UILabel`, and set image and text to both of this....then Place a custom button over imageView and Label....

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"]];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y,a,b)];
yourLabel.text = @"raj";
[self.view addSubview:yourLabel];

UIButton * yourBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[yourBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y,c,d)];
[yourBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(@"Your Action") forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:yourBtn];
```

Comment: Simple and useful. How to set highlighted image and title?

Comment: for lable setHighlightedTextColor and you have to play with forControlEvents

Answer (score 4):

You should create custom imageview for image and custom label for text and you add to your button as subviews. That's it.

```
UIButton *yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
yourButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(140, 40, 175, 30);     
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[self.view addSubview:yourButton];

UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, yourButton.frame.size.width, yourButton.frame.size.height/2)];
imageView1.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpg"];
[yourButton addSubview:imageView1];

UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yourButton.frame.size.height/2, yourButton.frame.size.width, yourButton.frame.size.height/2)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
label.textAlignment= UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.text = @"ButtonTitle";
[yourButton addSubview:label];
```

For testing purpose, use `yourButtonSelected:` method

```
-(void)yourButtonSelected:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Your Button Selected");

}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem, and I fix it by creating a new subclass of `UIButton` and overriding the `layoutSubviews:` method as below :

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Center image
    CGPoint center = self.imageView.center;
    center.x = self.frame.size.width/2;
    center.y = self.imageView.frame.size.height/2;
    self.imageView.center = center;

    //Center text
    CGRect newFrame = [self titleLabel].frame;
    newFrame.origin.x = 0;
    newFrame.origin.y = self.imageView.frame.size.height + 5;
    newFrame.size.width = self.frame.size.width;

    self.titleLabel.frame = newFrame;
    self.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

}
```

I think that the Angel García Olloqui's answer is another good solution, if you place all of them manually with interface builder but I'll keep my solution since I don't have to modify the content insets for each of my button.

Answer (score 3):

It's really simple,just add image to background of you button and give text to titlelabel of button for uicontrolstatenormal.
That's it.

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom];
[btn setTitle:@"Click Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: ...and how does the text go under the image?

Comment: @holex : Thank you very much for directing me,I found flaw in it and then changed accordingly.