# Add an image inside UIButton as an accesory

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uiimage

I have the following `UIButton` I want to add an Image inside to the far right. Like an `accessoryView`

I am already using  backgroundImage and I want to avoid combining the 2 images into 1.

Is it possible to add another image inside the UIButton that is an `AccesoryView` lets say an image that has a `PLUS` to the far right? ( I am looking to a way to insert the new image inside the Button)

[image]

@luisCien comment

I tried

```
    [_addImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shareMe"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   _addImage.contentHorizontalAlignment =
        UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
```

and it looks like this, I would like to image to be on the right side of the text. [image]

Comment: Here is a very simple solution that can be simply done by IB: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/11847383/5806009](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11847383/5806009)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add it as a subview and choose your coordinates..Try something like this:

```
UIImageView *yourPlusSign = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourPlusSignImageTitle"]];
yourPlusSign.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);//choose values that fit properly inside the frame of your baseButton
//or grab the width and height of yourBaseButton and change accordingly
yourPlusSign.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;//or whichever mode works best for you
[yourBaseButton addSubview:yourPlusSign];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `contentHorizontalAlignment` property of `UIButton` and set it to `UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight` this will position the image you add to it to the far right.

Edit:
As suggested by @danypata you can also use UIButton's property `imageEdgeInsets` to leave 
some margin around your 'accessoryView' like so:

```
[_addImage setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 5, 10)];
```

Regarding having the text on the left and the image on the right, I believe it's not possible (someone please correct me). For that I would either create my own custom button by extending `UIControl` or add a `UILabel` and set it's frame (as opposed to using `UIButton`'s `setTitle:forState:`) and add it as a subview of the button.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am looking a way to insert a new image inside.

Comment: Yes, that is no problem. UIButton has two methods for this, one is 'setBackgroundImage:forState:' and the other one is 'setImage:forState:'. Thanks to this you can add two different images, one as the background and the other one as the 'accessory view' that you want. There will be no collision

Comment: Thanks. I eddited my question to ask for a bit more guidance look at the bottom

Comment: @LuisCien You should complete your answer by adding the content insets, because the `UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight` is not enough.