# Is it possible to have a UIButton comprised of text, but at the end has an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, uilabel

For example, is a button like this achievable?

[image]

I've seen questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717219/uibutton-image-text-ios) where they go over how to put it before, which is indeed quite easy, but I'm not totally sure how to append it to the end of the text on the button when the text can be anything really. Conceptually, it would be something like having text, and then a UIButton say 10pt to the right of it.

Would the best way to do this simply be a `UIView` with a `UILabel` and a `UIImageView` inside it, with a tap gesture recognizer attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick sample :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrow.png"];
    [button setTitle:@"A Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button sizeToFit];

    CGRect imageRect = [button imageRectForContentRect:button.bounds];
    CGRect titleRect = [button titleRectForContentRect:button.bounds];

    UIEdgeInsets imageInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    UIEdgeInsets titleInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    titleInset.left = -2 * imageRect.size.width;
    imageInset.left = titleRect.size.width;

    button.titleEdgeInsets = titleInset;
    button.imageEdgeInsets = imageInset;
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    CGFloat prevHeight = button.frame.size.height;
    UIButton *anotherButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [anotherButton setTitle:@"Another Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [anotherButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [anotherButton sizeToFit];

    imageRect = [anotherButton imageRectForContentRect:anotherButton.bounds];
    titleRect = [anotherButton titleRectForContentRect:anotherButton.bounds];

    imageInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    titleInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    titleInset.left = -2 * imageRect.size.width;
    imageInset.left = titleRect.size.width;

    anotherButton.titleEdgeInsets = titleInset;
    anotherButton.imageEdgeInsets = imageInset;

    CGRect frame = anotherButton.frame;
    frame.origin.y += prevHeight + 4;

    [anotherButton setFrame:frame];

    [self.view addSubview:anotherButton];
}
```

[image: Result for 2 buttons create like this]

You just need to adjust buttons size and insets, if you want to add space between title and image.

Comment: Where does the frame of the first button get defined? And is `sizeToFit` necessary?

Comment: @DougSmith `sizeToFit` calculate the size of the button. So yes its necessary to send it, if you don't define a frame yourself. Without `sizeToFit` button.bounds and other rects will be equals to CGRectZero.

Comment: With this snippet in viewDidLoad the method never gets called when the button is tapped: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/28f2d5536ff2c1bd9482

Comment: @DougSmith Work without problem with `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` in my tests, be careful you use `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`.

Comment: Because I'm an idiot, thanks for catching that. My very last question is if I put it as `navigation.titleView` it works awesomely, but I'd like it centred based on the text, not the whole button (so therefore it would be slightly more to the right). Is it possible to push it more to the right if I set it to the titleView?

Comment: @DougSmith It may be possible, but not without some work like subclassing UIButton. And this is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just have a `UILabel` and a `UIImageView` and an invisible `UIButton` on top of them.

Or as you said, a `UIView` with you custom content and a gesture recognizer. In that case however it might be more difficult to achieve the same behavior as a regular button (no highlighting, you can't move your finger before letting go, etc.)

<del>Also, `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`. This means, you can easily add additional subviews (such as an `UIImageView`) inside the `UIButton`.</del>

<del>You could use an empty `UIButton` and put a `UILabel` and a `UIImageView` into it. And use Auto Layout to position them inside the button.</del>

Comment: Seems you can't add additional subviews to a UIButton in Interface Builder. Best to do in code then I assume?

Comment: Okay. When I use this snippet in `viewDidLoad`, the method never gets called. What am I doing wrong? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7736502

Comment: There is a reason why you cannot add the image in Interface Builder. Apple considers subviews of standard controls its implementation details and advises against adding you own subviews: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW26

Comment: Ah, fair enough. The search continues.

Answer (score 0):

Just create `UIButton`

```
UIImage *arrowDownImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowDown.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:arrowDownImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// set image and title Inset 

[button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(<#CGFloat top#>, <#CGFloat left#>, <#CGFloat bottom#>, <#CGFloat right#>)];
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(<#CGFloat top#>, <#CGFloat left#>, <#CGFloat bottom#>, <#CGFloat right#>)];
```

Play with Insets and this will give you exactly what you need.

This is IB example of button, but you can do the same programmatically.

[image]

And this is ImageInset

[image]

Title Inset

[image]

Comment: What kind of insets should I be trying?

Comment: Well^ if you what you image was inset from the left side of your button then use the  (width of you button - width of your image) value, just play with this values and you figure out what it gives you.

Comment: I don't see how this works when the text changes. It seems that it needs to be hardcoded.

Comment: If you button size changes dynamically, use button size to set Insets of the image and Text.

Comment: How do I get the button size without setting the frame? If I set the frame the size will never change, but if I use Auto Layout it seems that `button.bonds.size.width` is always 0.