# How to create a button with an icon on the right-hand side?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I am trying to put an icon next to a button label.

Problem: Interface Builder puts the button-image not to the right side. So there is still some space next to the (x).

Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: that is the same stuff but the text is under the image, you can adjust it for your particular wish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717219/uibutton-image-text-ios/11792816#11792816

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this in Interface Builder by setting the title and image insets:

[image]

In this case I've set the **title right inset to 30** and the **image left inset to 80**. You can achieve the same in code by setting the `UIButton`'s `imageEdgeInset` and `titleEdgeInset` properties. Knowing the size of the UIButton's subviews, you could probably calculate the edge insets using something like this:

```
CGSize labelWidth = myButton.titleLabel.frame.size.width;
CGSize imageWidth = myButton.imageView.frame.size.width;
myButton.titleEdgeInsets = (UIEdgeInsets){0.0, -imageWidth, 0.0, imageWidth};
myButton.imageEdgeInsets = (UIEdgeInsets){0.0, labelWidth, 0.0, -labelWidth};
```

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 8 you will find those attributes in the Size inspector:

[image: Xcode size inspector screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

select image(if (x) is image) or title (if (x) is simply key) on the window and set left , Right offsets according to your need

Answer (score -1):

i have achieved this:

```swift
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    
    open var rightIcon: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            rightIconImage = UIImageView(image: rightIcon?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))
            rightIconImage?.tintColor = .white
            if let rightIconImage = rightIconImage {
                addSubview(rightIconImage)
            }
            layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
    
    open override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setupRightIconIfNeeded()
    }
    
    func setupRightIconIfNeeded() {
        if let rightIconImage = rightIconImage {
            rightIconImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            titleLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            if let titleLabel = titleLabel, titleLabel.frame.width > 0 {
                let paddingLeft = (frame.width - titleLabel.frame.width - spacing - iconSize) / 2
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(constraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(titleLabel.constraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    //set height constraint for button
                    heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: apolloSize.height),
                    //set constraint for title label
                    titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: titleLabel.frame.width),
                    titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: titleLabel.frame.height),
                    titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
                    titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: paddingLeft),
                    //set constraint for right icon
                    rightIconImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: spacing),
                    rightIconImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.centerYAnchor),
                    rightIconImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSize),
                    rightIconImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSize)
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```