# SetImage is hiding title text... Can't Use background Image because I need EdgeInsets

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to add text to the bottom of my image but the setImage is hiding my text.

```
Top1.setImage(UIImage(named: "DefaultPic.jpg"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
Top1.setTitle("#1", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
Top1.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 0);
Top1.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0);
```

I can't use background image because I want the text and image to have a minor gap between them without having to use a seperate UILabel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717219/uibutton-image-text-ios

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564621/aligning-text-and-image-on-uibutton-with-imageedgeinsets-and-titleedgeinsets

Comment: @PiyushPatel I've looked at both of those examples earlier, they both still hide my text in ios8.  If I use background image then I wont be able to use inset on the image to create the gap I want

Comment: try this ..    Top1.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 5);
    Top1.contentEdgeInsets =UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 30, 0, 0);

Comment: @PiyushPatel That pushes the image to the right and the text is still hidden

Comment: so you button has height 30? and storyboard doesn't have any contentEdgeInset added?

Comment: @Dustin My Button has a width of 49 and height of 51

Comment: so your code moves image button bottom up only 10 and title top down 20...meaning still 21 points of overlap

Answer (score 0):

```
Top1.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 20, 0);
Top1.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(31, 0, 0, 0);
```

if you want `title` under `image`

Comment: Yes, I want the title under the image.  But this code still has my title hidden.

Comment: I'm trying view debugger...seems the title is empty. The `UIEdgeInsetsMake` is working properly for both image and title. I placed code to setImage(nil) this causes title to appear where desired...I don't understand why when Image is set title is hidden (meaning not visible, although properly offset)