# Xcode Button image top text below in a button not in code

Tags: ios, xcode

I create a button set image title like below picture.

I want

image

title

image on the top title below is it possible without any code?

I cant just use insets because to another size will wrong

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIButton Image + Text IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717219/uibutton-image-text-ios)

Comment: no one can fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Adjust both the title insets and the image insets.
It will need some calculations, and auto layout will probably screw it up ;)
Probably better to create a subclass of UIButton with a .xib

[click the link to view my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flPRo.png)